# Alternatives for $\rm He$ wavelength calibrator

Tags: spectroscopy

Where can I find a helium wavelength standard calibrator? We have a Photo Research WC-100, but seems we can't get anyone to do a calibration for it due to its age. Any leads to new vendors or alternative sources are appreciated.  We need it to calibrate yet another tool.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ed.  The range needs to be in the visible spectrum and it needs to be portable to the extent of moving it around a lab bench to a shelf.  We need it to calibrate a Photo Research PR-740 SpectroRadiometer.  Seems like I just need to use a different lamp like HgAr, so long as I can get clearly defined discrete spectral peaks.

For context I work on AR/VR R&D.

Comment: I think what we're looking for is sparse lines.  Easily identifiable peaks to calibrate our tool, or at least that's what's been explained to me.  I'm somewhat new to this part of metrology, so am learning quite a bit as I go.  But that's why helium worked so well, because of the very discrete sharp peaks in the visible range.  But then again, I will happily defer to your experience in the matter, so thank you again.  I'm still learning the procedure for calibrating the spectroradioscope, so I can't speak to what it really needs.

Comment: Based on what you say, I recommend looking online for the free Oriel Instruments Spectral Calibration Lamps manual. It is 26 pages and should give you a start. I have no connection with Oriel. Best of success! Also, I will delete my other comments very soon.

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks again for the advice and input!